# Object and Event Scope in XAML Frame

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a program which is made up of 5 "pages" and a main "page". How can events in one page trigger actions in other "pages"... or a control value set in one "page" be used in another "page"?

I have included the pages like this

```
    <Frame Source="GeneratorPage.xaml" />
```

Which I believe is the correct way... but I have had no luck assessing controls from within this frame outside it.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    Model myModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myModel = new Model();
        mainFrame.Navigate(new Uri(@"\myPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

As you can see here I create my model and navigate my frame to the page I wish to display. But how can my page access my model?

Comment: this is WPF right? in general you should avoid using controls of one page in another page, this couples the two pages together and will probably break when you change the controls in one of them. Try to expose properties and methods so you can call methods or retrieve a property value and not read content of UI control directly. This is normal OOP concept :-)

Comment: @DavidePiras thanks for your input. Yes this is WPF, everything is abstract, but I need two pages to share a model, I have a settings page and a main program page. The settings needs to read and write to the model and the main program needs to read the model. But I cannot seem to get the two UI's to share the same instance of the model.

Comment: how do you pass a reference to the model to the pages? can you show some code including the model and how you pass it to the pages?

Comment: @DavidePiras I'm not passing data to the between the view and the model that's what I'm stuck on. Updated question with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not include the model in the constructor of your `myPage` class

```
mainFrame.Navigate(new myPage(myModel));
```

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly. I wasn't aware .Navigate was able to take a new page as a parameter like that. I passed the model in by reference. And everything works perfectly.